# BibTex misc references show first three letters only

Tags: bibtex

I am using BibTex @misc for citing websites in my work.

```
@misc{test,
title =        {Test},
howpublished = {\url{https://test.com}},
note =         {Last accessed: 2018-08-25},
}
```

When I cite it like this \cite{test} in the output it results in tes, only. It is showing only the first three letters rather than the whole text test.

### Here, I am including a minimal example for that.

### abc.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{hyperref}    
% included other relevant packages.  
\begin{document}  
    Here, this is an minimal example \cite{test}.  
\bibliographystyle{apalike}  
\bibliography{abc.bib}  
\end{document}
```

---

### abc.bib

```
 @misc{test,  
    title = {Test Title},  
    howpublished = {\url{https://test.com}},  
    journal={ABC Journal}  
}
```

It outputs as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The citation output depends on both the bibliography/citation packages and the bibliography style you use. Please show us how you set up your bibliography and citation in a small example document. (That said, most non-numeric styles base their labels on author and year data, which you do not have in your entry.)

Comment: I think you may have accidentally created two accounts, one to post the question and one to edit in a MWE, if this is the case then you should bring this to the attention of a moderator and they will help you merge the accounts